# Sending query parameter and input value to a method

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, google-workspace, google-directory-api

looking for some help here please. So, I have a page that list the users from a group using the groupID as the parameter. Sometimes these list of users could be really long and I wanted to build in a search functionality to search the user(member) of the group.

I access the Workspace Directory API and method `members.list` like this:

```
const groupUsers = async function (groupid, from) {
  var members = [];
  var pageToken = '';
  var newPageToken = '';
  const admin = await authorizeDirectory();

  const resp = await admin.members.list({
    groupKey: groupid,
  });
  members = resp.data.members;
  console.log(members);
  //   console.log(members);
  //   members = resp.data.members;
  const total = members.length;
  return { results: members.splice(from, 10), total };
};
```

I then pass the response back to an index.js file that handles it for rendering to a handlebars template. Inside this template I have form that allows the user to enter the email address so that I can use it to search for it directly from the `members.get` method

My code for that is:

```
 <div class="searchWrapper">
        <form action="/group" method="GET" class="searchBar">
            <input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="Enter the user's email ID"
                value="{{this.term}}" />
            <span class="search-button">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="searchButton">FIND</a>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Could someone please help me understand how do I send the groupID and the value entered in the input search bar to the method, so that I can query the API. Would really appreciate the help.

My routes:

```
router.get('/group/:groupid', isUserAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const groupid = req.params.groupid;
  const from = parseInt(req.query.from || 0, 10) || 0;
  const members = await groupUsers(groupid, from);

  const pages = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(members.total / 10); i++)
    pages.push({ page: i * 10, label: i + 1 });

  res.render('groups', {
    members: members.results,
    total: members.total,
    groupid: groupid,
    from: from,
    pages: pages,
  });
  // res.send(`Group ID = ${req.params.groupid}`);
});
```

Comment: So, what exactly you are looking for? How to get the form data when user hits find?

Comment: I'm looking for sending the form data and the groupid from the previous page to the method

Comment: Have you created any routes in the project to handle the action on your form?

Comment: Yes. pasted and edited the text above

Comment: If I understand that correctly, you need to return the data from `groupUsers`? and then pass this data to the template

Comment: Sorry, not really. So, I have rendered a page with the response from the ``groupUsers``. Inside that page there is a form where I take the input from the user. I want to use the groupid and the user input to send to a method